# Share code in asyncData and mounted using Nuxt

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I want to share same code block to get data in asyncData and mounted using Nuxt.

For example in `asyncData`

```
  async asyncData({ $api, $auth, route, error, store }) {
    if( !process.server ) return null;
    let res = {};
    let stockData = await $api.stocks.getStock(route.params.name);
    if( stockData ) { res.stockData = stockData.data; }
    return res;
  },
```

And in `mounted()`

```
if(ObjectHelper().isEmpty( this.stockData )) {
  this.$api.stocks.getStock(route.params.name).then(res => {
    this.stockData = res.data;
  })
}
```

Those two code blocks are all getting data from server-side. How to write a common function to reuse it but not write twice? In nuxt documents, `You do NOT have access of the component instance through this inside asyncData because it is called before initiating the component.`

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand correctly - why would you like to do the call in both places?

Comment: In asyncData, it's for server-side rendering of nuxt. mounted is for client side if comes from other pages. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Ok. That is what I thought you’d like to do/ you think. But asyncData gets also called client-side.

Comment: Can you explain "But asyncData gets also called client-side. "?

Comment: @Tester he means that the API call inside your asyncData will be called everytime someone visits that site with asyncData, if you want to have a function that's called only on the server-side (meaning only once per session) have a look at [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action) which you place inside Vuex.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment to have the API call server and client-side, which is the reason for your question - it is not necessary to duplicate or share it within `mounted` as `asyncData`gets called server and client-side. You will find following in the nuxt docs:

> `asyncData` is called every time before loading the **page** component. It
>   will be called server-side once (on the first request to the Nuxt app)
>   **and client-side when navigating to further routes**.

That means - lets say you have your `asyncData` on page A and a user enters your site using page B and navigates client-side via a nuxt-link from page B to page A it will fire `asyncData` client-side too before initializing the page component.

Comment: Let's say I've an axios instance, where I've added the auth header. Is there anyway I can use that axios instance in asyncData. Right now I'm not able to make auth calls from asyncData.